Scraping element from web using rvest
I'm trying to scrape element from the website : https://diga.bfarm.de/de/verzeichnis
my goal is to create a table from all the class="entity-app"
library (rvest)
document <- read_html("https://diga.bfarm.de/de/verzeichnis")
html_products <- document %>% html_elements("entity-app")


my goal is to become the following result



entity-app__header__name
entity-app__info__list__header




First
row


Second
row



If someone had an idea or a line of thought, that would be very nice.
Thank you very much, dear future contributors.
;)

rvest is not the right tool here. I clicked the link and it looks like the contents are dynamically loaded with JavaScript. document <- read_html("https://diga.bfarm.de/de/verzeichnis") returns a German error message which translates as This page requires JavaScript. Please enable JavaScript in your browser settings..  You should look at using a headless browser, e.g. through RSelenium.

rvest has an experimental function called read_html_live() that can scrape webpages that dynamically generate JavaScript. Try read_html_live("https://diga.bfarm.de/de/verzeichnis") |> html_elements(".entity-app__header__name") |>  html_text2() for instance.

This worked for me if it helps (using rvest's read_html_live and placing the results in a two-column data frame):
library(tibble)
library(rvest)

sess <- 
  read_html_live("https://diga.bfarm.de/de/verzeichnis") 

Sys.sleep(5)

tibble(
  header = sess |>
    html_elements(".entity-app__header__name") |>
    html_text2(),
  info = sess |>
    html_elements(".entity-app__subheader") |>
    html_text2()
)
#> # A tibble: 57 × 2
#>    header                                                             info      
#>    <chr>                                                              <chr>     
#>  1 actensio                                                           Vorläufig…
#>  2 Cara Care für Reizdarm                                             Dauerhaft…
#>  3 companion patella powered by medi - proved by Dt. Kniegesellschaft Dauerhaft…
#>  4 deprexis                                                           Dauerhaft…
#>  5 edupression.com®                                                   Dauerhaft…
#>  6 elevida                                                            Dauerhaft…
#>  7 elona therapy Depression                                           Vorläufig…
#>  8 Endo-App                                                           Dauerhaft…
#>  9 glucura Diabetestherapie                                           Vorläufig…
#> 10 HelloBetter Chronische Schmerzen                                   Dauerhaft…
#> # ℹ 47 more rows

Created on 2024-05-06 with reprex v2.1.0

i got the following error: 'Error in new_chromote && !self$session$is_active() :
invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'

Do you have the chromote package installed? And a copy of Google Chrome installed on your machine?

As documented here.

@rtremeaud I got that same error when I tried to use read_html_live() without first running library(chromote). Install chromote install.packages("chromote") then library(chromote), then read_html_live() should not error the way it did before.
